# How do I check the reactions on a Discord message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently creating a giveaway command. It should be checked who reacts to the message from the bot. If no one reacts to the message the bot should output that no one has reacted to the message. But for me it always shows that nobody has reacted to the message even though reactions exist. Does anyone here see the error?

```
        my_msg = await ctx.send(embed=e)

        await my_msg.add_reaction("")

        await asyncio.sleep(mins * 60)

        new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

        if len(new_msg.reactions and my_msg.reactions) == 0:
            await ctx.send("No one reacted.")
        else:
            winner = random.choice([u for u in await my_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten() if not u.bot])
            e = discord.Embed(color=self.bot.color)
            e.title = "Giveaway ended!"
            e.description = f"You won: {prize}"
            e.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            e.set_footer(text=f'{self.bot.user.name}',
                         icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(f"{winner.mention}", embed=e)
```

Comment: `len(new_msg.reactions and my_msg.reactions)` gives you the length of `new_msg.reactions and my_msg.reactions`, but you want `len(new_msg.reactions) == 0 and len(my_msg.reactions) == 0`

Comment: @Dominik I think you want to get rid of the `await` in the list comprehension. Not sure.

Comment: @Grismar Thanks for the answer! This now just gives me the output `winner = random.choice([u for u in await my_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten() if not u.bot]) IndexError: list index out of range` in the console. How would I have to change this?

Comment: @Guimoute After removing the `await` in `random.choice([u for u in AWAIT my_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten() if not u.bot])` I just get the same error as mentioned in the command to Grismar. Somehow the method is not catching things right...

Comment: Then that means `new_msg.reactions` is the only one with elements and `my_msg.reactions` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to check `my_msg`. It is the message object at the state of sending it, even after adding reactions to it or changing it on discord, `my_msg` object in your code will not have that info.

That is why `new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)` is there. new_msg has all that information.

Bringing us to `len(new_msg.reactions)`. It will never be `0`, remember. your bot reacted to it, and that reaction counts, so `if len(new_msg.reactions) == 0` is not something you can get.

Get the list of users who reacted to the message before doing the check, making sure not to include the bot in that list.

```py
    ...
        my_msg = await ctx.send(embed=e)
        await my_msg.add_reaction("")
        await asyncio.sleep(set_time)
        new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

        user_list = [u for u in await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten() if u != self.bot.user]

        # After we have the list, we can check if any users reacted
        if len(user_list) == 0:
            await ctx.send("No one reacted.")
        else:
            winner = random.choice(user_list)
            e = discord.Embed()
            e.title = "Giveaway ended!"
            e.description = f"You won:"
            e.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            e.set_footer(text=f'{self.bot.user.name}',
                         icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(f"{winner.mention}", embed=e)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I understand what you were doing there and will have  a further look into this. This method works!