# Giveaway Command Not Responding

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a giveaway command but I'm having trouble making it select a winner and send the winner embed. It sends the "New Giveaway Started!" embed just fine and reacts to it, but it won't send the winner embed saying the giveaway is over and who won it. I'm getting no errors as well. My code is

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_role('Giveaways')
async def gcreate(self, ctx, time=None, *, prize=None):
        if time == None:
          await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, you need to give the duration! `Example: 1m, 1h, 7d`')
          return
        if prize == None:
          await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, you need to give the prize!')
          return
        embed=discord.Embed(title='New Giveaway Started!', color=0x1CDEA3)
        embed.add_field(name='Prize:', value=f'{prize}', inline=False)
        time_convert = {"s":1, "m":60, "h":3600, "d":86400}
        gawtime = int(time[0]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
        embed.add_field(name='Duration:', value=f'{time}', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='From:', value=f'{ctx.author.mention}', inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'{ctx.guild.name}')
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

        gaw_msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await gaw_msg.add_reaction("")
        await asyncio.sleep(gawtime)
        new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(gaw_msg.id)

        user_list = [u for u in await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten() if u != self.bot.user]

        # After we have the list, we can check if any users reacted
        if len(user_list) == 0:
          await ctx.send("No one reacted.")
        else:
          winner = random.choice(user_list)

        winnerembed=discord.Embed(title='Giveaway Ended', description=f'**{winner}** won the giveaway for\n***{prize}*** !', color=0x1CDEA3)
        winnerembed.set_footer(text=f'{ctx.guild.name}')
        winnerembed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        winnerembed.set_thumbnail(url=winner.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=winnerembed)
        await ctx.send(winner.mention)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have an error handler? if so, comment it out and see if there is an error

Comment: @Guddi I only have a few to log certain errors. But not one for stuff like this.

Comment: are you sure they dont block this error? anyways you can add a `try:`  before `await asyncio.sleep(gawtime)` and `except Exception as e: print(e)` after `await ctx.send(winner.mention)` - use the command again and hopefuly you will get an error msg now

Comment: If you have discord.py error handlers like on_command_error i suggest you to remove them, run the bot, try the command and then send the full error log here.

Comment: Of course, when you log the error, readd the error handler.

Comment: @Guddi I tried this and it made the command started working completely! I guess it needed `try:` ? I don't know it's weird

Comment: @Guddi Except sometimes, i get this error in the console, `Cannot choose from an empty sequence` Yet I reacted to the message.

Comment: do you have the members intent active?

Comment: @Guddi Yes i do.

Comment: @Guddi It seems to throw the error when the giveaway time is 10 seconds or higher.. but it works fine when the time is below 10 seconds.

Comment: Is this helping you? [How do I check the reactions on a Discord message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65151080/how-do-i-check-the-reactions-on-a-discord-message)

Comment: @Dominik I tried this, but say for example i put `30s` for the duration, it only holds the giveaway for 3 seconds. It's only taking the first number, not the second number. It was not doing this before. I updated my question with current code.

Comment: @ColeTMK So what is the problem now? Just the time being incorrectly converted?

Comment: @Dominik So say i give any number with an s after it. So like if I say `15s`.. the giveaway would only last 1 second. It only took the first digit out of it, it didn't take the 5. But whenever I give a digit that ends with a `m` , `h` , `d`, it would take all the digits and work fine. So yes it could be converting the wrong way. My code to convert the time is `time_convert = {"s":1, "m":60, "h":3600, "d":86400}
        gawtime = int(time[0]) * time_convert[time[-1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from the comments I assume that everything works now except for the time. This is due to a small mistage in your `gawtime` converter.

**Try this function instead:**

```py
gawtime = int(time[:-1]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
```

`time[0]` is always 1 and therfore 10s will be one second and `time[-1]` is `m` so it will be converted to 10 seconds.